# Changing excutablePath wont work in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

i've just search for puppeteer data scraping.
But the problem is even when I had changed the exutablePath to installed chrome.
The chromium window keep open whenever i launch the puppeteer instead of google chrome.

Here is the code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false,executablePath:'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1280,
    height: 800
  });
  await page.goto("https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/",{waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});
  await page.screenshot({
    path: 'test.png',
    fullPage: true
  });

  await browser.close();

})();
```

[I captured the screen, my google account should have been signed in for me, but It did not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yigjr.png)

Answer (score 0):

it can be something with your path. but alternatively you can use broswerFetche to fetch any version of chrome or firefox. [versions](http://omahaproxy.appspot.com/)

```js
const browserFetcher = puppeteer.createBrowserFetcher();
const revisionInfo = await browserFetcher.download('533271');
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: revisionInfo.executablePath})
```

from [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.4.0/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions)

Comment: I actually just want it to use my google account to sign in the web, not downloading another version of chrome

Comment: @MinhLêPhanCông do you try use Path from node packages ? (https://nodejs.org/api/path.html)